# sync postgres table with json data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an endpoint to get information in json format

```
[
  {
    id: 123,
    name: 'a name',
    code: '123SDF',
    category: 'some category'
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    name: 'a another name',
    code: '234SDF',
    category: 'some category'
  },
  etc...
]
```

And I need to sync that with a local table I have.  I was just truncating and adding but now I need to update or insert.  The reason is because I am adding columns to the local table.  local table has these columns:

```
id,
name,
code,
category,
template
```

So I can no longer truncate because I will lose the template field.  What query can I run so it will update if the id is found, otherwise insert with null for my extra fields?

The id will be the same for both json data and my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose there are multiple ways to accomplish this. You could configure your table to make the `id` column unique, then have an `ON CONFLICT` clause to do an update when the row already exists.

However here's a way to do it without changing anything about your table.

1. Transform the data (just makes things easier)
2. Do an UPDATE and find out which ids were updated
3. Do an INSERT for whichever ids were not updated

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INTEGER, name TEXT, code TEXT, category TEXT, template TEXT);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (123, 'a name', 'a code', 'a cat', 'a template');
```

Poor man's upsert:

```
WITH
  source_data AS (
    SELECT (j->>'id')::INTEGER AS id,
           j->>'name' AS name,
           j->>'code' AS code,
           j->>'category' AS category
    FROM JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(
      '[
        {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "a name",
        "code": "123SDF",
        "category": "some category"
        },
        {
        "id": 234,
        "name": "a another name",
        "code": "234SDF",
        "category": "some category"
        }
      ]'::JSON) j
  ),
  updated AS (
    UPDATE t
    SET name = s.name,
        code = s.code,
        category = s.category
    FROM source_data s
    WHERE t.id = s.id
    RETURNING t.id
  )
INSERT INTO t
SELECT id, name, code, category, NULL
FROM source_data s
WHERE s.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM updated);
```

Result of doing a `SELECT * FROM t` after the upsert:

```
| id  | name           | code   | category      | template   |
| --- | -------------- | ------ | ------------- | ---------- |
| 123 | a name         | 123SDF | some category | a template |
| 234 | a another name | 234SDF | some category |            |
```

You can see the template value of the existing record was not overwritten.